# From varnish to AWS Cloudfront, traffic volume estimate

Tags: amazon-web-services, varnish, amazon-cloudfront, bandwidth

I'm setting up Amazon Cloudfront in front of (maybe in place of) varnish and I want to estimate the cost.

I can consider the sum of the fields `s_bodybytes` and `s_hdrbytes` of varnistat as monthly traffic to be indicated in the "aws simple monthly calculator" (http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) for CloudFront ? (obviously calculated in a correct time period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those appear to collectively represent total bytes sent to clients, so that should be a reasonable approximation of the amount of "out to the Internet" traffic for CloudFront usage charge estimation.

There are other charges, a per-request charge and a charge for upstream bandwidth between CloudFront and the origin server, but those should be negligible in comparison, for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get an accurate estimate this way. I would suggest also to take into account number of requests you are receiving (CloudFront also has a per-request fee), and cachability of your objects to calculate number of requests (and data transfered) for content from origin

Comment: Note that CloudFront no longer charges for transport from the origin to CloudFront when the origin is in EC2... only from CloudFront to origin (uploads and request headers).

Comment: Thank Alex, i want to estimate the Data Transfer Out to the Internet, not traffic between CloudFront and origin EC2 (as rightly says @Michael-sqlbot no longer charges)